# How to add new specs content via impex on electronic store provide by hybris?

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

Hybris comes with an OOTB Electronics store.  All the products have a Specs page with a long list of specs.  Any anyone point to some documentation on how to add or remove one of those specs via impex and/or code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure which exact page you have mentioned about. In general, all the product data related ImpEx files are in ⁨hybris⁩ ▸ ⁨bin⁩ ▸ ⁨modules⁩ ▸ ⁨b2c-accelerator⁩ ▸ ⁨electronicsstore⁩ ▸ ⁨resources⁩ ▸ ⁨electronicsstore⁩ ▸ ⁨import⁩ ▸ ⁨sampledata⁩ ▸ ⁨productCatalogs⁩ ▸ ⁨electronicsProductCatalog⁩. Most likely, you are looking for `products_en.impex` in this path.

You can insert new data or update the existing data by executing similar ImpEx. Check [here](https://help.sap.com/viewer/d0224eca81e249cb821f2cdf45a82ace/1905/en-US/1c8f5bebdc6e434782ff0cfdb0ca1847.html) for information on ImpEx syntax.